# How to fetch javascript results w/ Twig

Tags: javascript, php, twig

I am not sure how I can pass a variable from my JS folder to my Twig templates. It is a variable that takes true/false on page load and needs to be used inside an If statement to execute responsive code.

I tried calling the name of the variable itself but as I found out that doesn't work.

JS Script

```
var isMobile = (function() {....})();
```

Twig template

```
 {% if isMobile %}
  <div>Small div</div>
  {% else %}
  <div>Big div</div>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better and more convenient doing with Javascript itself.

```
<div id="yourDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div
```

In Javascript do something like this.

```
 var el = document.querySelector('#yourDIV');//to target multiple divs use class
 if (isMobile()) {
   el.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "none";
 }
```

*This is an idea, you can modify it as per your need.*

Comment: It is a lot of code that needs to be squeezed into JS including Twig syntax and I am not sure if that is wise to do.

Comment: @Kostis Twig is PHP, Javascript and PHP can't communicate directly they can only with AJAX. For more information on the topic have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php